# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxkeymap==0.1

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on Heroku. But the following error is shown when it is built:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxkeymap==0.1

Comment: Heroku tries to install packages from your requirements.txt using `pip install`. Unfortunately, lxkeymap is part of the system Python packages (`apt install`) and not available via `pip install`. Are you using a virtual environment? How did you generate your *requirements.txt* file?

Comment: If it's just a regular Flask app, then you shouldn't be requiring lxkeymap.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, [lxkeymap](https://helpmanual.io/packages/apt/lxkeymap/) is a system application that is installed via `apt` and is NOT available via `pip`. As explained in [Python Dependencies via Pip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip), Heroku uses `pip` to install your app's dependencies.

I am guessing that when you generated your *requirements.txt* file, **you also included the system packages**, maybe by using `sudo pip freeze` or by not using a Python virtual environment or by manually writing the requirements file yourself.

```
$ sudo apt-get install lxkeymap
$ sudo pip freeze | grep lxkeymap
lxkeymap==0.1
```

Heroku will expectedly fail because `pip install lxkeymap` will fail.

The solution here is to use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to manage your app's dependencies. I doubt that you would need `lxkeymap` for your Flask app, so it should not be required to be included in your *requirements.txt* file (Flask certainly does not need it). You should only put those packages your app *directly* needs.

1. [Create and Activate a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) for your app
2. Install packages one-by-one as you need them (**DO NOT USE `sudo`**):

   ```
   (myflaskenv) myflaskapp$ pip3 freeze  ## This should be initially empty.
   (myflaskenv) myflaskapp$              

   (myflaskenv) myflaskapp$ pip3 install Flask
   (myflaskenv) myflaskapp$ pip3 freeze
   Click==7.0
   Flask==1.0.2
   itsdangerous==1.1.0
   Jinja2==2.10.1
   MarkupSafe==1.1.1
   Werkzeug==0.15.2
   ```
3. Generate your *requirements.txt* from your virtual environment (again, **DO NOT USE `sudo`**)

   ```
   (myflaskenv) myflaskapp$ pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
4. Use the *requirements.txt* file from your virtual environment when uploading to Heroku.

See [Managing packages with pip](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#managing-packages-with-pip) for more info.